# Images over HTTPS endless issues - mixed content

Tags: content, ssl

I've installed a SSL certificate on my site : https://whiskas.co.za and now I'm getting the mixed content issues, I've tried most of the stuff found on the www but no go :-(

[image: h]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use a migration plugin to update all the URLs? Those look like they're coming from uploads, so probably saved in `post_content` of the posts where you have added images. That would be fixed by running a migration plugin to update all the URLs.

Comment: Great, thanks I appreciated the help. What plugin do you suggest?

Comment: You need to search the database and replace the old site URL with the new https version

Comment: Best method is to export your database into a text file (something.sql) if you are using mysql. Search & replace http:// with https: where it refers to your domain name. Then, backup your original db and delete the tables. Now re-import the exported and updated file.

Comment: Hi all, thanks fr hte assistance, really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, text search and replace will likely cause issues, because if any values are serialized they will break. Look for "database migration plugins" and you will find several good options.